# std::terminate and destructors of empty containers

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, noexcept, exception-safety

Consider some standard container which uses dynamic memory (i.e. is an [AllocatorAwareContainer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/AllocatorAwareContainer)) and has a size and capacity of zero. For example, take a `std::vector` and call `vec.resize(0); vec.shrink_to_fit();`.

I would imagine that such container instances would contain only `nullptr` pointers for their logical contents and `std::size_t` members to track information like `size`. I would also imagine that their destructors would do essentially nothing, as there is no dynamic memory to be freed.

All destructors of containers, as I know, are `noexcept`. I.e. on throwing of an exception during destruction they should call `std::terminate`. It is possible in case of `Allocator::deallocate()` throw exception.

Can I be sure containers in the state, described above, never call `std::terminate` on destruction?

Comment: Sorry, can you reword your first two paragraphs. I am not able to understand the requirement from it.

Comment: @Arunmu Not sure. I use google translate, and that's all I can out of him.

Comment: @Arunmu If the question is really poor formulated you just can vote to close it.

Comment: I really do not want to do that. Can you instead try to provide another code example with little comments on it. If thats more clear then I can edit the question.

Comment: I rephrased the opening paragraphs, feel free to rollback if you don't like the changes.

Comment: Ok, so is the question about deleting null pointer in containers destructor by the allocator ? In C++ delete on a null pointer is NOT an undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Arunmu Roughly speaking, this is a question about: is it possible that `}` call `std::terminate` in statement `{ std::container c = ...; c.clear(); c.shrink_to_fit(); }`?

Comment: Example was really irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, in case the container stores elements that can throw while copying (in case move is not noexcept) or while moving (in case of noexcept). The container might give a basic or strong guarantee in such cases, but if you do not catch the exception, it will call std terminate.

Comment: My above comment was for std::vector

Comment: `shrink_to_fit` is only an advise. The container is allowed to keep some buffer allocated.

Comment: @IlyaPopov yeah, but then thats implementation defined.

Comment: What would such guarantee be useful for? The program may be terminated for million and one other reasons (power failure, out-of-memory, external signal, etc.) at any point anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is possible in case of `Allocator::deallocate()` throw exception.

No, it's not. The requirements for `Allocator` forbid `deallocate` to throw. It's not a formal `noexcept` specifier, but C++14 Table 28 Allocator requirements says:

> a.deallocate(p, n) [...] Does not throw exceptions.

So if your allocator throws on deallocation, that's a violation of the required contract and all bets are off anyway.