# Allocator::deallocate exception-related design nuances

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, memory-management, allocator

I tried to design `xallocator` — C++ allocator of **executable**/readable/writable memory. It used along with `std::vector` (I need a contiguous storage) to store code, generated by JIT-compiler. For *C++11* and later it looks like:

```
#include <memory>
#include <limits>
#include <new>
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cassert>

template< typename type >
struct xallocator
{

    using value_type = type;

    xallocator() = default;

    template< typename rhs >
    constexpr
    xallocator(xallocator< rhs > const &) noexcept
    { ; }

#ifdef PAGESIZE
    [[gnu::assume_aligned(PAGESIZE)]] // -DPAGESIZE=`getconf PAGESIZE` for Linux xor -DPAGESIZE="alignof(std::max_align_t)" for Windows
#endif
    value_type *
    allocate(std::size_t n) const;

    void
    deallocate(value_type * p, std::size_t n) const;

};

template< typename lhs, typename rhs >
constexpr
bool
operator == (xallocator< lhs > const & /*_lhs*/, xallocator< rhs > const & /*_rhs*/) noexcept
{
    return true;
}

template< typename lhs, typename rhs >
constexpr
bool
operator != (xallocator< lhs > const & _lhs, xallocator< rhs > const & _rhs) noexcept
{
    return !(_lhs == _rhs);
}

#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)

#include <windows.h>

template< typename type >
auto
xallocator< type >::allocate(std::size_t n) const
-> value_type *
{
    if (n == 0) {
        return nullptr;
    }
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant"
    ::LPVOID const p = ::VirtualAlloc(NULL, n * sizeof(value_type), (MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (p == NULL) {
        throw std::bad_alloc{};
    }
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
#ifdef PAGESIZE
    assert(0 == (reinterpret_cast< std::uintptr_t >(p) % PAGESIZE));
#endif
    return static_cast< value_type * >(p);
}

template< typename type >
void
xallocator< type >::deallocate(value_type * p, std::size_t n) const
{
    if (p == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    if (::VirtualFree(static_cast< ::LPVOID >(p), 0, MEM_RELEASE) == FALSE) {
        throw std::bad_alloc{};
    }
}

#elif defined(__linux__)

#include <sys/mman.h>

template< typename type >
auto
xallocator< type >::allocate(std::size_t n) const
-> value_type *
{
    if (n == 0) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    void * p = ::mmap(nullptr, n * sizeof(value_type), (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC), (MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS), -1, 0); // insecure
    if (p == MAP_FAILED) {
        throw std::bad_alloc{};
    }
#ifdef PAGESIZE
    assert(0 == (reinterpret_cast< std::uintptr_t >(p) % PAGESIZE));
#endif
    return static_cast< value_type * >(p);
}

template< typename type >
void
xallocator< type >::deallocate(value_type * p, std::size_t n) const
{
    if (p == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    if (::munmap(static_cast< void * >(p), n * sizeof(value_type)) == -1) {
        throw std::bad_alloc{};
    }
}

#endif
```

But recently I find, that `deallocate()` function [shouldn't throw any exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34676852/1430927). Therefore I safely should mark it by `noexcept` specifier.

But what to do if I can't deallocate allocated (by means of corresponding API's) memory in `deallocated()` member function due to error code returned? Should I manually call `std::terminate` or allow to do it for compiler (by means of throwing `std::bad_alloc` into `deallocate() noexcept`)? Or should I simply ignore the error?

I sure it is very unlikely, when `VirtualFree`/`munmap` returns error code, but I should still be correct even in such a rare cases.

Comment: Feel free to edit the question and especially title.

Comment: Is there a memory management API that returns an error on deallocation?

Comment: @n.m. On Windows is `VirtualFree == FALSE`, on Linux is `munmap == -1` as you can see handled in the code above. But I don't know a conditions for this to occur. Maybe it is an impossible branches indeed.

Comment: OK so this may (mostly?) happen when user tries to free memory that he didn't allocate. `free` or `delete` would just crash and burn (undefined behaviour). so I think `terminate` would be an appropriate response.